# Yii cookie based login don't work

Tags: php, authentication, yii

main.php

```
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'loginUrl'=>array('site/prijava'),
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
```

LoginForm.php

```
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
```

I didn't change this code from defaut yii application. When I check "remember me" and  login I have to login again when I close browser. I checked $duration, it is set to 3600*24*30. Same behavour is in Chrome and Mozzila, and cookies are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need also to set application ID in your `main.php`

```
'id' => 'myapp',
```

Comment: Same thing... Maybe it is a problem of having many variables (and arrays) on login which I put with setState(), and when I delete some of them it creates cookie and then works. Maybe it is a problem with lenght of cookie (4KB). I need all that information, and What should I do?

Comment: Try to specify `session->savePath` and make sure it's writable.